# How to delete single Local Storage element using a link without jQuery

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am using this example code as the basis for a proof of concept on a some Local Storage functionality I'm working on.

[How to use local storage in Javascript and output the stored elements in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878481/how-to-use-local-storage-in-javascript-and-output-the-stored-elements-in-a-table)

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="highscores"></ul>
```

**JS:**

```
var hst = document.getElementById("highscores");

var highScores = [
    {name: "Maximillian", score: 1000},
    {name: "The second guy", score: 700},
    {name: "The newbie", score: 50},
];

localStorage.setItem("highscores", JSON.stringify(highScores));

var retrievedScores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("highscores"));

for (var i = 0; i < retrievedScores.length; i++) {
    hst.innerHTML += "<li>" + retrievedScores[i].name + " -- " + retrievedScores[i].score + "</li>";
}
```

That works fine, and generates List Items like:

```
<li>Maximillian -- 1000</li>
<li>The second guy -- 700</li>
<li>The newbie -- 50</li>
```

On the page that outputs the Local Stage elements, I'd like to add a link to each one so that it can be deleted.

At the moment, the above code uses standard Javascript, without jQuery.

Is there any way I can achieve that?

I tried this in the output of the list items:

```
hst.innerHTML += "<li><a href='#' onClick='localStorage.removeItem(\"" + retrievedScores[i] + "\");'>Delete</a> - " + retrievedScores[i].name + " -- " + retrievedScores[i].score + "</li>";
```

But clicking on the delete link doesn't delete the items.

I also tried:

```
hst.innerHTML += "<li><a href='#' onClick='localStorage.removeItem(\"" + retrievedScores[i].name + "\");'>Delete</a> - " + retrievedScores[i].name + " -- " + retrievedScores[i].score + "</li>";
```

That also had no effect.

Reading this:

[How to delete an array element stored in local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36888969/how-to-delete-an-array-element-stored-in-local-storage)

I see it says about having to set things again after the delete, but I am not sure how I would do that using the simple example I am working with above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using unique id for each element. And then remove element from array than save to LocalStorage.

**JavaScript**

```
var deleteById = function ( id ){
  retrievedScores = retrievedScores.filter(function(elem) {
      return elem.id !== id;
});
```

Example solution based on your code:
 https://codepen.io/szymongabrek/pen/QMmeyQ

Answer (score 0):

You would not remove the item from local storage. Local storage only has a string representation of all the data. Instead you remove the object from the array (`retrievedScores`) and write it again to local storage.

Example (considering what you have so far):

```
var hst = document.getElementById("highscores");

var highScores = [
    {name: "Maximillian", score: 1000},
    {name: "The second guy", score: 700},
    {name: "The newbie", score: 50},
];

localStorage.setItem("highscores", JSON.stringify(highScores));

var retrievedScores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("highscores"));

function removeScore(i) {
  highScores.splice(i, 1);
  localStorage.setItem("highscores", JSON.stringify(highScores));
}

for (var i = 0; i < retrievedScores.length; i++) {
    hst.innerHTML += "<li><a href='#' onClick='removeScore(" + i + ");'>Delete</a> - " + retrievedScores[i].name + " -- " + retrievedScores[i].score + "</li>";
}
```

There are certainly more elegant ways (instead of using inline event handlers and creating DOM elements via HTML), but it would do. One caveat using inline event handlers: The function has to be defined in global scope. But however you bind the handler, the principle is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you add an **id** property to each entry in the array. I recommend you to use a button instead of a link, but a link will work as well

The example code is below. to see a demo go to this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/ManuelDavid325/dzjarhk4/1/

```js
var hst = document.getElementById("highscores");

var highScores = [
    {id: 1, name: "Maximillian", score: 1000},
    {id: 2, name: "The second guy", score: 700},
    {id: 3, name: "The newbie", score: 50},
];

localStorage.setItem("highscores", JSON.stringify(highScores));

var retrievedScores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("highscores"));

for (var i = 0; i < retrievedScores.length; i++) {
    hst.innerHTML += "<li id=\"score-"+retrievedScores[i].id+"\"><button onclick='deleteEntry(\""+retrievedScores[i].id+"\")'>Delete</button>" + retrievedScores[i].name + " -- " + retrievedScores[i].score + "</li>";
}

window.deleteEntry = function(id){
    // Delete the item from the array
    retrievedScores = retrievedScores.filter(val => val.id !== id);
    // Update the array on the localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("highscores", JSON.stringify(highScores));
    // Delete the item from the table
    document.getElementById("score-"+id).remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="highscores">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Direct solution***

You can simply filter the array using [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.

then restore the new array into `localStorage`

**HTML**

```
<li>Maximillian -- 1000 <a href="#" onClick="removeLsItem('Maximillian')"> Delete  </a></li>
<li>The second guy -- 700 <a href="#" onClick="removeLsItem('The second guy')"> Delete  </a></li>
<li>The newbie -- 50 <a href="#" onClick="removeLsItem('The newbie')"> Delete  </a></li>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function removeLsItem (name) {

  var getItems = localStorage.getItem('highscores');
  var itemsArr = JSON.parse(getItems);

  var ItemsAfterDelete = itemsArr.filter(function (oldItem) {
    return oldItem.name !== name;
  });

  // Update Stored Items
  localStorage.setItem('highscores',  JSON.stringify(ItemsAfterDelete));

}
```

---

*`id` is very important because it's unique value. will prevent unexpected logical mistakes when is duplicated.*

---

**Another solution (better for me)** (with only one line JavaScript)

> Because dealing with `localStorage` object is very boring using VanillaJS.
>
> for example you need to use `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` every time you `set` or `get` an item.

Then it's better to use a helper library for `localStroage`.

I recommend [This library](https://github.com/mohamedabbasos/typed-dom-storage) for `localStorage` / `sessionStroage`.

You can re-write previous code in one line using `ls.removeByIdFrom` function that do all your remove from array from `localStroage` object.

***EX:***

**HTML**

```
<li>Maximillian -- 1000 <a href="#" onClick="removeLsItem(1)"> Delete  </a></li>
<li>The second guy -- 700 <a href="#" onClick="removeLsItem(2)"> Delete  </a></li>
<li>The newbie -- 50 <a href="#" onClick="removeLsItem(3)"> Delete  </a></li>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// You need to edit this array and add id
var highScores = [
    {id: 1, name: "Maximillian", score: 1000},
    {id:2, name: "The second guy", score: 700},
    {id:3, name: "The newbie", score: 50},
];

// new remove function
function removeLsItem (id) {
    ls.removeByIdFrom(id, 'highscores');    
}
```